# Retracting a close vote doesn't seem give you the vote back

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

Currently, unless I'm missing something, you don't seem to get the close vote back when you retract it. You also don't appear to get the vote back when a question that you voted to close is deleted. However, you *do* get the downvote back when you retract it or the question you downvoted is deleted.

Is this a bug? It seems like they should behave in the same way.

Comment: How are you testing this?  Are you just looking at your vote count on your profile, because that's not updated in real time.

Comment: @Servy For the downvotes, I hit my daily max, retracted one of the downvotes, and was allowed to vote again on something else. However, I don't seem to be able to do the same thing for close votes.

Comment: This is [status-bydesign].  Retracting just cancels your vote, it doesn't actually return it to your close vote pool.

Comment: @NathanOliver The linked question is different - that one's asking why you can't vote to close the question again once you retract a previous vote on it, I'm asking why you don't get the vote back.

Comment: It's the same reason.  You have spent the vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close votes aren't counted like up/down votes; they're counted more like flags. An obvious (and probably familiar) difference is that you can vote on the same post many times (provided you retract your previous vote first) but you can only flag or vote-to-close a given post once.

A less obvious difference is that retraction is considered more or less the same as any other status that resolves a flag: the flag (or close vote) still exists, and still counts as your one shot at that particular post, but is simply no longer considered active in the system.

One could easily imagine a design that opted for a stronger similarity between flags/close-votes and up/down votes - in such a system, a validated flag would no longer count against your limit for the day, thus allowing you to keep flagging (or voting to close) as long as your flags/votes were being actioned promptly. (This is how downvotes work: if you're in the habit of downvoting posts which are soon deleted, you can keep doing it all day long without ever exhausting your supply of downvotes.)

Comment: I was thinking of posting a question about something similar to this not so long ago. Say for example I chose a generic close vote (unclear let's say) that I could have closed in one go with a gold tag I have but felt it did not match the problem, yet someone else closed it with a duplicate but I don't agree nor does it have anything to do with the problem and it gets reopened, why should I have lost my vote because of someone else's (voting) mistake? Or, should I post a question about it, or has it been asked/answered already?

Comment: If folks are reopening an unclear question that hasn't been clarified, that's a bigger problem than a lost vote, @Fred. Note that we recently added the ability for gold-badge holders to *edit* duplicate links specifically to handle those cases where a question gets dup-hammered against the wrong original.

Comment: By "unclear", that was just an example (I should have used a better example, say more like "why it's not working" and there was indeed something that didn't work *somewhere*) and that my vote was a valid one, and yes I know about the *edit* duplicate option which is a fine addition, I use it often ("*One of the best thing since sliced bread"*). I was thinking that the scenario(s) could be anything really, it's mostly about losing a vote for someone else's mistake which is the basis of my question.