# Why are aren't flags returned to the user after being accepted?

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags

I am going to use stack overflow as an example but it is more of a general question.

From Stack Overflow's help:

> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may
>   increase to up to 100 flags per day

In other words, if you use up all of your flags for the day you have to wait ~24 hours before you can flag posts again.

Wouldn't it be more reasonable to just return the flag to the user after it is approved (deemed *helpful*) similar to how edits work?  Of course there should probably still be a 24 hour reset period for those flags that never get accepted, declined, or disputed.

Is there a reason it was set up to refresh after 24 hours instead of returning the flags after they are used like SO does with edits? (i.e. Is it to prevent clutter or was there a pattern that caused this?).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353807/retracting-a-close-vote-doesnt-seem-give-you-the-vote-back

Comment: @Patrice My apologies.  I saw "This question may already have an answer here:" and thought that came from a duplicate flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retracting a close vote doesn't seem give you the vote back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353807/retracting-a-close-vote-doesnt-seem-give-you-the-vote-back)

Comment: @Stephen That post almost explicitly deals with just close votes, while mentioning flag behavior in passing. This question is entirely about the flag behavior, not close votes.

Comment: @TinyGiant, yes but the answer to that post does explain the logic behind behavior.

Comment: @Stephen The answer posted there does not adequately answer this question. It is a relevant reference for the topic, but it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like the reason would be wrapped around the fact that the number of flags allowed to a person can be increased...not much point in increasing the number of flags if they are returned after approval.  So your more appropriate question would be:  "How can i get the number of flags allowed increased?"  because that is the apparent mechanism chosen for the feature.  Number of flags could be functioning as a metering device on the system to prevent an absolute flood on approves.  How does a person get more flags?

Comment: main reason is probably that proficient flaggers tend to reach "absolute limit" of 100 flags relatively quickly (in 2-3 months) after which it doesn't matter anymore

Comment: @Drt "How can i get the number of flags allowed increased?"  would be a pretty stupid question given its stated right in the help section of SO.  The mechanism still works even if they gave flags back after being accepted.  " Number of flags could be functioning as a metering device on the system to prevent an absolute flood on approves" is more the type of answer I am looking for.  But I am looking for a definitive answer not a thought process (As I stated that rational in the question already)

Comment: I'm surprised to see votes suggesting this idea is so unpopular. It seems pretty reasonable to me, actually.