# Raise a duplicate flag after a retracted closure flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Let's say I flagged a question for low quality, being unclear or too broad. I retracted the flag since the author improved his question and I now notice (because the author elaborated his question) that this question is in fact a duplicate of an already answered question.

I can't flag this question as a duplicate anymore because it will be locked with the message:

> You have retracted your recommended closure flag

[image]

The category "**should be closed...**" is probably locked to prevent abuse of the flag retraction, but wouldn't it makes sense to still have the option to mark a question as a duplicate after retracting a different close vote, since both these votes can be independent?

*edit:* 
I know of the one flag per question policy, but shouldn't this be an exception since voting for a duplicate is a whole different reason as any of the other closure flags?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense. But you only get a close vote / flag per question, and that's it.

Comment: @yivi I can still flag for spam or abuse though. What I'm saying is that the duplicate close vote should be handled independently, since it is a whole different reason.

Comment: Spam and abuse are not reason to close a question, but to delete a question. So those are independent. Again, not saying I do not agree to certain extent with you; just telling you is like this by design. E.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353807/retracting-a-close-vote-doesnt-seem-give-you-the-vote-back

Comment: *since voting for a duplicate is a whole different reason as any of the other closure flags* ... no, it is the same thing both lead to closure. That duplicate is a separate option there is for convenience, nothing else. As a matter of fact you can vote to close for duplicate again if you choose *should be closed*