# When flagging a post, why are we not allowed to retract and flag as something else?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, retracted-flags

A few times now, I have flagged a post for not having enough details and later needed to flag it for something else. If the user updates their post to add detail, I'll often retract the flag. Sometimes though, the users new details make it obvious that the problem is a duplicate for instance. However, now that I have already flagged it and retracted it for something else, I can't flag as a duplicate. Why? could we change the current system to allow this?

Comment: This is consistent with how close-votes work, which isn't surprising, as the system handles both close-flags and close-votes very similarly. In general, the guideline is to just leave the close-flag or close-vote active unless the question should no longer be closed. The caveat to that for close-votes is you may choose to retract the close-vote if you see the question will be closed for a reason which the OP might find confusing. That can be handled by either: leave a comment that a different close reason applies, or retract the close-vote and hope a now-appropriate reason is used by others.

Comment: DoS attack counter-measure, probably.

Comment: For discussion of why you cannot vote to close for a different reason, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254778). See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262657/) for *changing* the close reason. Also related: [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353807/retracting-a-close-vote-doesnt-seem-give-you-the-vote-back). As Makyen said, close votes and flags are handled nearly identically by the system.

Comment: @CodyGray A followup question, if you will: One of the above references talks a lot about the close reason not mattering, which I don't fully understand. I don't have enough rep yet to know how the close system works, but I doubt that people looking at a post flagged for not enough info are going to go look for a duplicate answer, no? They'll just vote not to close it as there is info.

Comment: @CodyGray All of these discussions are also quite old, definitely think this is a case worth reopening.

Comment: The close review queue is going to present all of the close reasons chosen, whether from votes or flags, to the reviewer, so if at least one person chose that option, then yes, it will be considered by all subsequent reviewers. We do ask that reviewers look at *all* of the problems with a question when they are reviewing, so even if you flag as "too broad", but someone thinks it's actually "off topic", they'd still vote to close the question. In fact, we recommend that people vote to close for whichever reason they think is most appropriate, not just blindly follow the leader.

Comment: Flagging/closure as duplicate is perhaps a bird of a different color, since you have to actually go looking for a duplicate. Reviewers are less likely to do that without prompting. You can help prompt them by leaving a comment like the system would have done for a real duplicate vote. Something like, "Possible duplicate of <link>"

Comment: @CodyGray I understand the system I suppose, just seems flawed to me, or at least could be improved upon in a substantial way.

Comment: It may well be. Note that I did not close this question as a duplicate. I don't think any of those previously-linked discussions are actually duplicates, and I do agree that it is perhaps worth reconsidering. I do think that the system is slightly flawed in this regard, and certainly has room for improvement. But, realistically speaking, don't hold your breath waiting for it to be so improved. In the mean time, hopefully understanding how it does work will let you use it as effectively as possible.

Comment: @CodyGray it absolutely does, thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Laif if it helps, if I see a question that seems to lack details, I try to ask for them in a comment. I'd come back to the question some time later (say,10-30 minutes. Sometimes an hour or two) and *then* cast any votes, if appropriate. So, if there has still been no change, I'd go for a vote for that. If the question has been updated but is now a dupe or a typo or falls under any other close reason, I vote for that. I try to make a judgement call - some questions just don't seem like they need extra time for details, so I'd vote immediately.

Comment: @VLAZ If a question is missing essential details, you should not be waiting *any* length of time to vote to close. There is no purpose in waiting, and in fact, it’s actively harmful, as it decreases the odds that the question will get closed. You can still leave a comment clarifying exactly what is missing. And if/when that information is added, you can always reopen when you check back.